# PHP (7.1) inheritance issue

Tags: php, inheritance, php-7

I have the following structure:

```
class AffiliateRepository extends GenericRepository implements IAffiliateRepository {

}


abstract class GenericRepository  {
    public function save(BaseModel $model) : int{
        $model->save();
        return $model->getId();
    }

}

interface IAffiliateRepository  {

    public function save(Affiliate $affiliate) : int;
}

public class Affiliate extends BaseModel{}


$affiliateRepository  = new AffiliateRepository();
$affiliateRepository->save(new Affiliate());
```

I am expecting `GenericRepository` to take care on the save action.

but I'm getting the following error:

`Declaration of App\Services\AffiliateRepository::save(App\Models\Affiliate $affiliate): int 
should be compatible with 
App\Services\GenericRepository::save(App\Models\BaseModel $model): int`

Why is that? `Affiliate` inherits from `BaseModel`.
Whats the best way to overcome that and let `GenericRepository` handle the `save` function call.

thanks

Comment: Because the method signature of `GenericRepository::save` is not met. That method says that it can accept any `BaseModel`, whereas `IAffiliateRepository::save` only accepts `Affiliate` instances. So it clearly breaks the contract.

Comment: Is \App\Models\Affiliate a descendant of \App\Models\BaseModel?

Comment: *"Why is that? Affiliate inherits from `BaseModel`."* -- because PHP is not C++ :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at methods:

```
// GenericRepository
public function save(BaseModel $model)

// IAffiliateRepository
public function save(Affiliate $affiliate) : int;
```

Both classes have to expect the same type. If you implement `IAffiliateRepository` into `GenericRepository` class, it will be correct. You may also need to change variable names to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit messy but the problem is, in order for `AffiliateRepository` to implement the `IAffiliateRepository`, the signature of `save` must be

```
save(Affiliate $affiliate) : int
```

The implementation in `GenericRepository` does not satisfy this.

You could try this in `AffiliateRepository`...

```
public function save(Affiliate $affiliate) : int {
    return parent::save($affiliate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@enricog gave the correct answer in a comment: to satisfy the interface the `save` method must accept any object that is a `BaseModel`. The method provided by `IAffiliateRepository` does not do that.